# Two different page numbers, first set without the first page number

Tags: ms-word

I can't seem to get how to do this, I need two sets of page numbers, the first set starts from i, ii, iii etc. The second set starts from 1, 2, 3, etc. For the first set, page i should not show the i, but page 1 should show the page number. If I removed the page i number, then page 1 also vanishes, anyone know how to handle this?

Comment: You're on the wrong network, my friend. This is a programming site.